# Shortcode - Display all terms of an attribute into an ordered list by alphabetical letters

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, taxonomy

I've created a simple shortcode to output attribute terms and link to their respective archives. I'd like to be able to split the results by letter so that they output as follows:

```
A
Adidas
Askwith

B
Bonham
Burberry
```

...which would in HTML look like this:

```
<span id="a">A</span>
<ul class="brandlist">
<li><a href="/brand/adidas">Adidas</a></li>
<li><a href="/brand/askwith">Askwith</a></li>
</ul>

<span id="b">B</span>
<ul class="brandlist">
<li><a href="/brand/bonham">Bonham</a></li>
<li><a href="/brand/burberry">Burberry</a></li>
</ul>
```

But I'm at a bit of a loss on how to do this. I've read a few articles that suggest creating a new custom taxonomy for the letters but that seems to be a long way around to doing something that I hope is solvable in a simpler way.

Here's the shortcode I've created so far:

```
function brands_output( $atts ){

    ob_start();
    echo '<ul class="brandlist">';

    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'pa_brand',
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        )
    );

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $brand = $term->name;
    $slug = $term->slug;

    echo '<li><a href="/brand/'.$slug.'/">'.$brand.'</a></li>';
    }

    echo '</ul>';
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    return $output;

}
add_shortcode( 'showbrands', 'brands_output' );
```

How an I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your fully functional shortcode. I have test it with a different set of terms and it works perfectly (so I hope that yours is correct and working too).

> First I prepare the data in a bi-dimentional array with the alphabetical letters on level 1 and the corresponding terms pair name/slug on level2.
>
> After I iterate in this bi-dimentional array to make the display you want to have…

Here is the code:

```
if (!function_exists('showbrands')) {
    
    function showbrands(){
    
        $term_arr = array();
    
        $terms = get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_brand',
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'hide_empty' => false,
        ) );
    
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $brand = $term->name;
            $slug = $term->slug;
    
            // Getting the first letter of $brand term name
            $letter = substr($brand, 0, 1);
            
            // PREPARING DATA IN A BI DIMENSIONAL ARRAY
    
            // Inserting the $letter in an array just once (array level 1)
            // Inserting for each letter all the corresponding pairs "$brand => $slug" (array level 2)
            if(!array_key_exists($letter, $term_arr))
                $term_arr[$letter] = array($slug => $brand);
            else
                $term_arr[$letter][$slug] = $brand;
        }
    
        $output = '<div class="brandlist-container">';
    
        // ITERATING IN THE BI DIMENTIONAL $TERM_ARR ARRAY 
        
        // first level the letters
        foreach( $term_arr as $key_letter => $terms_in_letter ){
            $output .= '<span id="'. strtolower( $key_letter ) .'">'. $key_letter .'</span>
                  <ul class="brandlist">';
    
            // second level the $brand / $slug pairs
            foreach( $terms_in_letter as $key => $value ){
                $output .= '<li><a href="/brand/'.$key.'/">'.$value.'</a></li>';
            }
            $output .= '</ul>';
        }
        $output .= '</div>';
        
        return $output;
    }
    
    add_shortcode( 'showbrands', 'showbrands' );
    
}
```

*This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.

Comment: Thats awesome, thank you, however its outputting the slug as the brand and the brand as the slug e.g <a href="/brand/Awdis Academy/">awdis-academy</a> when it should be <a href="/brand/awdis-academy/">Awdis Academy</a>.

Comment: I've marked answer as correct but could you please fix it so that it outputs the link correctly? For anyone checking this out I just switched the  $output .= '<li><a href="/brand/'.$key.'/">'.$value.'</a></li>'; to  $output .= '<li><a href="/brand/'.$value.'/">'.$key.'</a></li>'; Cheers.

Comment: @d1ch0t0my ah yes … sorry just a little inversion… I have updated code. thanks